# Command to yield just the linux distribution name only

Tags: linux, distributions, software-distribution

Suppose I have a set of pre-requisites I need to install for any of a number of linux distributions.  In this case, I'd need to switch my install expression against the distribution.

I am aware of `uname -v`, and I am aware that I can inspect the output of this command with some friable string expression and logic. However what I really need is:

```
V=$(something-like-uname)
echo $V

"Debian"
# or
"Gentoo"
# or
"Redhat"
# or 
"Arch"
# etc.
```

What is this command? (Does it exist?)

Comment: AFAIK there is no posix standard for this so it's going to be different from distribution to distribution.  There are plenty of examples out there of code that determines distribution though.

Comment: What about packaging using the various common package systems, like `apt` and `yum`, instead of trying to write an installer that does the right thing? Or write a Linuxbrew formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd always check `lsb_release -i` first and then check
`/etc/os-release` as the fallback.  It should be available on *many*
distributions but you can never count on it being everywhere of
course. It's [Freedesktop
standard](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/os-release.html)
and is present on [systemd
systems](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/os-release.html). On
Slackware it shows:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME=Slackware
VERSION="14.2"
ID=slackware
VERSION_ID=14.2
PRETTY_NAME="Slackware 14.2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;34"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:slackware:slackware_linux:14.2"
HOME_URL="http://slackware.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/"
```

And on Raspbian:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

The field you're interested here is probably `ID`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
grep -Po "(?<=^ID=).+" /etc/os-release | sed 's/"//g'
```

Comment: This file doesn't exist on my centos machine, or on my debian machine.

Comment: `-bash: lsb_release: command not found`

Comment: Edited the answer to use os-release that seems to exist on Debian, Ubuntu, and Centos

Comment: `/etc/os-release` doesn't seem to be on my debian machine

Comment: It is in my debian and centos docker images.

Comment: Yeah my debian is pretty old, debian 6.  I think OPs issue is much more complicated than a single command though.

Answer (score 1):

`lsb_release -i` might do what you want if it is installed. Otherwise the trick it to check for files like `/etc/redhat-release`, `/etc/debian_version`, etc.

```
$ lsb_release -i 
Distributor ID: Fedora
```